# HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID always changing MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to detect where the user is logged in from another system. I tried some of the code. Which is

After logged in 
1) Save System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID into Database
2) Match this value in Database. If the session values different it will send an email.

But System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID is always different when logged in from the same system. I logged in from Chrome the System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID is alwasy different.

How can I detect into correct way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to understand that session is maintained per user per browser. It means if you have logged in with same user from `chrome` and `firefox` and `IE`, you will have three different sessions for the same user. Secondly, if your `Session.ID` is changing two often, you probably have small value set as session timeout in web.config. Please check your `web.config` and look for the code that sets session timeout. It should be under `confiugration` and then under `system.web` like the following

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The above code sets the session timeout to 20 minutes.

Comment: What happen If i use the same browser. Is the session same?

Comment: yes, for same browser, it should stay the same unless it times out